# Python 2.7 Regex Tokenizer Implementation Not Working

Tags: regex, python-2.7, tokenize

I created a regular expression to match tokens in a german `text` which is of type `string`.

My Regular expression is working as expected using [regex101.com](https://regex101.com). Here is a link of my regex with an example sentence: [My regex + example on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ys1BRp/1)

So I implemented it in `python 2.7` like this:

```
GERMAN_TOKENIZER = r'''(?x) # set flag to allow verbose regex
([A-ZÄÖÜ]\.)+  # abbrevations including ÄÖÜ
|\d+([.,]\d+)?([€$%])? # numbers, allowing commas as seperators and € as currency
|[\wäöü]+ # matches normal words
|\.\.\. # ellipsis
|[][.,;\"'?():-_'!] # matches special characters including !
'''

def tokenize_german_text(text):
    '''
        Takes a text of type string and 
        tokenizes the text
    '''
    matchObject = re.findall(GERMAN_TOKENIZER, text)
    pass

tokenize_german_text(u'Das ist ein Deutscher Text! Er enthält auch Währungen, 10€')
```

Result:

[image: result]
When I was debugging this I found out that the `matchObject` is only a list containing 11 entries with empty characters. Why is it not working as expected and how can I fix this?

Comment: Additional note: You might want to compile your regex with the `re.UNICODE` option in order to allow `\w` to match non-ASCII letters - after all, there are German words that contain accents other than umlauts, and you're missing those right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re.findall()` collects only the matches in capturing groups (unless there are no capturing groups in your regex, in which case it captures each match).

So your regex matches several times, but every time the match is one where no capturing group is participating. Remove the capturing groups, and you'll see results. Also, place the `-` at the end of the character class unless you actually want to match the range of characters between `:` and `_` (but not the `-` itself):

```
GERMAN_TOKENIZER = r'''(?x) # set flag to allow verbose regex
(?:[A-ZÄÖÜ]\.)+  # abbrevations including ÄÖÜ
|\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?[€$%]? # numbers, allowing commas as seperators and € as currency
|[\wäöü]+ # matches normal words
|\.\.\. # ellipsis
|[][.,;\"'?():_'!-] # matches special characters including !
'''
```

Result:

```
['Das', 'ist', 'ein', 'Deutscher', 'Text', '!', 'Er', 'enthält', 'auch', 'Währungen', ',', '10€']
```